# How to plot a function with n-terms

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot this function:

```
FullSimplify[(t Cos[(m^2 Pi^2)/9 + (n^2 Pi^2)/9] + t Sin[(m^2 Pi^2)/9 + (n^2 Pi^2)/9]) Sin[(n Pi x)/3] Sin[(m Pi y)/3]]
```

but since it contains n- and m-terms, and it has a time-dimension, it is certainly not straight forward. How do I plot this in Mathematica for various time steps with discrete values for m and n?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to make a function. Change `n` and `m` to pick the mode of vibration using the slider. Move the `time` slider to change the time. The `x,y` are hardcoded ranges.  The plot range is fixed in order to better capture the motion scale.

Change as needed.

[image]

code

```
ClearAll[n, m, x, y, t, f];
f[n_, m_, t_, x_, y_] = 
 FullSimplify[(t Cos[(m^2 Pi^2)/9 + (n^2 Pi^2)/9] + 
     t Sin[(m^2 Pi^2)/9 + (n^2 Pi^2)/9]) Sin[(n Pi x)/3] Sin[(m Pi y)/
     3]]
Manipulate[
 Module[{x, y},
  Plot3D[f[n, m, t, x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3},
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-5, 5}},
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"time ", t}]
   ]
  ],
 {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{n, 2, "n"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{m, 3, "m"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t, n, m}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I see clearly that this is a solution to the wave equation in two dimensions .

Answer (score 3):

There are three main reasons to visualize anything:

- Discover
- Confirm
- Explain

Which of these are you trying to accomplish?

Fiddling with your equation a bit to restructure it...

```
TrigFactor[(t Cos[π^2/9 + (n^2 π^2)/9] + t Sin[π^2/9 + (n^2 π^2)/9]) Sin[(n π x)/3] Sin[(π y)/3]]
```

TrigFactor works with it in a way that makes clear various effects.

```
t (Sqrt[2] Sin[π/4 + (m^2 π^2)/9 + (n^2 π^2)/9]) Sin[(n π x)/3] Sin[(m π y)/3]
```

By examination you can see a lot of what is going on. The expression is linear in `t`, has a constant term `(Sqrt[2] Sin[π/4 + (m^2 π^2)/9 + (n^2 π^2)/9])` that is determined by `n` and `m`, and has the oscillating terms in `x` and `y` with frequencies set by `n` and `m` respectively.

@Nasser's approach is a great way to explore the equation and get some intuition.